# Inventor/Co-inventor later removed from application and patent without knowledge

Tags: patent-infringement

I was the original inventor and became partners w(co-inventor). The initial application was denied in 2005. I left the company and just found out that the initial application was approved 2012 with my name removed from patent.

Do I have any recourse? There plenty of documentation that I was inventor on web.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I would talk to an attorney. Business partners and co-inventors are two different things entirely. Everyone who made a *conceptual contribution* to something *claimed* in an application should be named as an inventor. It is possible, if you were co-inventors, that a new application was filed that only claimed things that you did *not* contribute to. Otherwise it is improper. Yet a different issue is the ownership. Inventors and co-inventors are automatic owners but they may have an agreement to assign their rights to a company, partnership or to one of the inventors.